# Determine ListboxItem position in a canvas?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my WPF Application I have a canvas with a Listbox in it. I want to overlay an Listboxitem with another control after it was clicked on the item. But for that I need the position of the Listboxitem in the canvas.
I see the problem because the single Item is not child of the canvas. Only the Listbox itself is.

Is there any way I can get the relative position of the ListboxItem in the canvas or maybe the absolute position inside the window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this code:

```
Point p = listboxItem.TranslatePoint(new Point(0.0,0.0),Window.GetWindow(listboxItem));
```

In order to get it relative to the canvas, replace the new Point to the canavas location.

HTH.

Comment: I found the time to try this. Works like a dream. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but I wonder if the [Adorner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737(VS.85).aspx) concept of WPF may give you what you want.